# Changing ProgressBar visibility from inside onClick

Tags: android, onclick, visibility, android-progressbar

My activity_main.xml contains this progressBar, which starts hidden ("gone")

```
<ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar_sendingPhoneNumber"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/button_sendPhoneNumber"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:visibility="gone" />
```

And my MainActivity.java has this, 
An onClick handler for a button I have

```
    final Context context = this;

    sendPhoneNumberButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_sendingPhoneNumber);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Simulate HTTP connection
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Redirect to new activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, InboxActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the progress bar is never shown, although the onClick code is executed (eg. it is redirected to the new activity at the end). So the line:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Isn't taking effect.

I think this has to do with the context, and trying to change the visibility of the progressBar from "outside" the activity, but i'm not sure.

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the `Context` you're using. You're blocking the UI `Thread` for three seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never shown because you are calling

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

that makes "sleep" the thread responsible to draw the same `ProgressBar` you are trying to show

Comment: but that piece of code is after changing the visibility to "visible"

Comment: I know. But you have to wait the next draw() is executed. This will happen sometime in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Calling  `Thread.sleep(3000);` on the UI thread will block the UI thread. You should not block the UI thread.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

> If you implement Thread or HandlerThread, be sure that your UI thread
>   does not block while waiting for the worker thread to complete—do not
>   call Thread.wait() or Thread.sleep()

Also, you can move this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_sendingPhoneNumber);
```

outside `View.onClick`. No need to initialize the view every time you click your `Button`.

Comment: I mean, it is the same if he put invisible or gone as value for the visibility attribute in the xml.

Comment: @blackbelt ok. it has nothing to do with gone. unwanted